# Portable Access Database Provider for .NET connection

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

Is it possible to connect to an Access Database (*.accdb) from within .NET application without having MS Access (not even redistributable engine) installed, but just packing ACEOLEDB.dll along application files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have revised my previous answer as I now realise that it was incorrect and I apologise for that. It was my experience that it was impossible to access a .accdb database without MS Access installed.  Now I realise that if you have the access database engine installed than yes you can. However if this is not installed than no you can not have a working application that needs to interact with that type of database.

Comment: This is not correct

Comment: This is *mostly* incorrect as all the dupe links indicate.  MS-Access does provide UI for administering, but that is not what the question asks and you dont often allow end users to fiddle with the app's data store, structure etc.  It **does not** supply the DLLs for connecting, that is all contained in NET.  However you sometimes have to install an Access Redistributable depending on the bitness of the OS versus your app.